# Is there a coding convention to MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, calling-convention, abi, mips32

I would like to get linked with a C compiler.

- What is the convention to pass values to function using MIPS?
- Is there a coding convention or RFC-Like document?

Comment: Did you do any research? Have you for example checked [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS)  at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no correct way, with assembly language you can do whatever you want.

But if you are trying to link with a C compiler for example then, why dont you just try using the compiler you have?  It obviously can create objects that link with other objects made by the same compiler.

```
extern unsigned int more_fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b );
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    unsigned int c;
    c = more_fun(a,b+7);
    return(c+a+5);
}
```

this is what mine produces (with certain flags), object not linked...

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   27bdffe8    addiu   sp,sp,-24
   4:   24a50007    addiu   a1,a1,7
   8:   afbf0014    sw  ra,20(sp)
   c:   afb00010    sw  s0,16(sp)
  10:   0c000000    jal 0 <fun>
  14:   00808025    move    s0,a0
  18:   8fbf0014    lw  ra,20(sp)
  1c:   26100005    addiu   s0,s0,5
  20:   02021021    addu    v0,s0,v0
  24:   8fb00010    lw  s0,16(sp)
  28:   03e00008    jr  ra
  2c:   27bd0018    addiu   sp,sp,24
```

I think that spells it out, and gives you a way to figure it out for more complicated parameters or return values.   I prefer to compile and disassemble to compile to assembly.  Much easier to read and actually see what is produced.  YMMV.

Comment: You can get rid of the "noise" in normal gcc `-S` output in a few ways.  The easiest is usually using Godbolt, which has MIPS and MIPS64 gcc5.4 installed.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/g/JrbUQD.  Unfortunately its usual filtering of assembler directives and comments seems to not be doing a good job on the 32-bit output, and the function-call is loading the function address into a register instead of using a direct jal.  I guess there's a code-model option I don't know about?  Anyway, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output.

Comment: Although assemble + disassemble may still be better for MIPS, since gcc output uses numbered registers like `$31` instead of `ra`.

Comment: I build my own binutils and change it from the s0,a0,ra (ewww) to register numbers with a simple patch...I think arm binutils now needs the same patch.